# How to add xcframework as dependant framework for pod(A) in iOS?

Tags: swift, xcframework

I tried adding it in podspec of my development pod as s.dependancy, 'ab.xcframework'. Pod is getting installed correctly in sample application, but this framework is not added as dependancy for the dev pod.

Comment: Please post your Podfile and details about your project configuration; is it a single Xcode project with both the app and frameworks targets, or multiple Xcode projects?

Comment: Hi Esther, did you get any solution for this. If you found any can you please share it here?